# Deploying Spring Boot + Angular (4) to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a Spring Boot application, packaged in a WAR which I uploaded onto Elastic Beanstalk. So far, so good: my REST endpoints can be contacted, database is working fine.

I then included some static content in the WAR, namely an Angular (4) app. Locally, this works like expected: when running the war, after my endpoints are mapped, Spring picks up the index.html file and serves it as my welcome page (line 4). When surfing to localhost:5000, the Angular app shows up.

```
2017-08-12 17:13:45.413  INFO 8660 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 17:13:45.414  INFO 8660 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 17:13:45.462  INFO 8660 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 17:13:45.517  INFO 8660 --- [           main] oConfiguration$WelcomePageHandlerMapping : Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
2017-08-12 17:13:46.065  INFO 8660 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-08-12 17:13:46.145  INFO 8660 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)
2017-08-12 17:13:46.152  INFO 8660 --- [           main] b.n.g.MyApplication            : Started MyApplication in 70.311 seconds (JVM running for 70.76)
```

However, on Elastic Beanstalk, this serving-of-the-index.html line is missing, and I'm not finding a way to get my Angular app to show up:

```
2017-08-12 15:45:16.655  INFO 21219 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 15:45:16.656  INFO 21219 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 15:45:16.745  INFO 21219 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-08-12 15:45:17.730  INFO 21219 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-08-12 15:45:17.840  INFO 21219 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)
2017-08-12 15:45:17.850  INFO 21219 --- [           main] b.n.g.MyApplication            : Started MyApplication in 11.8 seconds (JVM running for 12.765)
```

**What am I missing here?**

- Is this related to NgInx?
- Is it simply not possible for Elastic Beanstalk to serve static / html / js (angular) files which are packaged in the WAR? If so: why not...?
- If it's not possible: I guess the solution is deploying my backend on Elastic Beanstalk and placing the Angular frontend on S3?

Comment: I would recommend the option 3 mentioned by you which will be a separation of concern.

Comment: Did you ssh into the instance and checked the files being deployed correctly? Finally, the simplest solution is to use static files namespace provided by beanstalk (in ebextenion) or create your own nginx conf and put that into ebextension. In nginx conf you can provide url path and location on beanstalk instance against it.

Comment: @Niels have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Junaid, In the end I went for separate deploys (deploying my backend on Elastic Beanstalk and placing the Angular frontend on S3).